# When does a map between CW-complexes give a relative CW-complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $X$, $Y$ be (absolute) CW-complexes and $\varphi:X\to Y$ a continuous map. I would like to know under which assumptions $(Y,\varphi(X))$ is a relative CW-complex.

I got interested in this question in a more specific case, i.e. when $Y=X$ and $\varphi$ is homotopic to the identity of $X$. However, I don't have many knowledge on algebraic topology to know related results, so every help would be appreciated.

**P.S.** I already know that this works if $\varphi(X)$ is a subcomplex of $Y$.

Comment: I believe it is irrelevant whether $X$ is CW-complex or not. The answer only depends on $\varphi(X)$, and even if $X$ is a CW-complex, you do not know much about  $\varphi(X)$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2505862. By the way, I guess you allow that the cells of $(Y, \varphi(X))$ are completely different from those of $Y$?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I can understand your belief, but I was hoping to find assumption on X rather than on the nature of $\varphi$. Also, you guess right, I have no interest in which possible CW structure we give to $(Y, \varphi(X))$.

Comment: A minimal requirement is that the inclusion $\varphi(X) \hookrightarrow Y$ is a cofibration, and I doubt that this can be assured by assumptions on $X$.

Comment: Here is an example. Let $X = D^3$ = three dimensional closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It admits an embedding $\varphi : D^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that the complement of $A = \varphi(D^3)$ is not simply connected. An example is the Alexander horned ball (which is enclosed by the Alexander horned sphere https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere). The quotient $\mathbb{R}^3/A$ is not simply connected, therefore $\mathbb{R}^3/A$ is not homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^3$ which would be a consequence if $A \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ would be a cofibration.